# REGEX To Find Acronyms Outside of Parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex, editing

I'm trying to find all instance of an acronym outside enclosing parenthesis; e.g., I'm looking for FO, but not (FO). While the term can be defined as an acronym; e.g., Faint Objects (FO), the acronym is only used in specific instances (FO I/FO II). Except for these instances, the acronym needs to be spelled out in the document.

To complicate it, I also need to find instances where the acronym is used in a parenthetical phrase; e.g., (FO are hard to see) and (like non-FO). In these instances, the acronym also needs to be spelled out.

I tried:

```
(?<!\x28)HQ(?!\x29)
```

Which works well except for (FO are hard to see); i.e., acronym preceded by parenleft.

Comment: In the text I'm editing, the acronym needs to be spelled out except for when it is defined and in the specific uses shown.

Comment: How do you know that for instance 'Faint Objects' is an acronym 'FO' spelled out?

Comment: BTW: You can use `\(` instead of `\x28`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it's rendered un-ambigous like this :

```
FO(?<!\(FO(?=\)))
```

https://regex101.com/r/Rkz9oN/1

```
 FO
 (?<!
    \( FO
    (?= \) )
 )
```

This uses a compound nested assertion.

*Note that:*  If using the new JS engine with variable length look behind
the `FO` can be variable and used as a back reference :

```
(FO)(?<!\(\1(?=\)))
```

https://regex101.com/r/jxFSmX/1

This facilitates finding multiple Acronyms in a single regex guarded by this assertion :

```
(FO|FQ|FRY|HW)(?<!\(\1(?=\)))
```

https://regex101.com/r/OCEmNy/1

In-fact you can have every single Acronym you can type or cut'n paste)
put into a trie regex generator (https://regexformat.com/scrn8/TernSort.jpg) making it a formidable tool.

Comment: Thanks much for the solution.  It worked perfectly.  Unfortunately, ExtendScript for Adobe FrameMaker does not support variable length look behinds...I wish it did.

Comment: If you have the time and interest, I'd like to take the regex one step further.  While it finds all instances of FO outside of parenthesis, I also need it to find all instance of FO followed by a "I" or "II" (Roman numerals).  FO I & FO II are correct and I don't need to select them, but FO-I, FO-II, FOI, and FOII are incorrect and I need to find and correct them.

Comment: The following finds the FO- and FO in FO-I and FOI, but also finds FO I, which I don't want to select.                                                                                                                                FO-?(?=\w?)(?<!\(FO(?=\)))

Comment: @gator - It might be that _`ExtendScript for Adobe`_ only supports ECMAScript 3. Which might not even support _lookbehind assertions_. If it doesn't an entirely new  regex is needed. For now, this fixed-length lookbehind assertion regex will find only FO, FO I, FO II. `FO(?<!\(FO(?=(?:[ ]I{1,2})?\)))(?!-?I)(?:[ ]I{1,2})?`
https://regex101.com/r/cDVjjo/1
. This regex will find the bad FOI, FOII, or FO-I, FO-II. `FO-?I{1,2}`
https://regex101.com/r/Q5V5kB/1

Comment: Many thanks for your help on these.  Yes, ExtendScript for Adobe FrameMaker is based on ECMAScript 3, but apparently has some enhancements such as support for  lookbehind assertions; e.g., (?<=FO)-?[II]{1,2} will select the I, II, -I, -II following in FOI, FOII, FO-I, and FO-II.  Your regex examples have given me some new ways of looking at my my searches.  I'm self taught on JavaScript and Regex, so there's much that I don't know.

Comment: No problem, glad it at least has a lookbehind capability. I tried to find ExtendScript regex syntax but had no luck.

Comment: Hang in there Rome wasn't built in a day !